# Is there any option to run github action via email

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-runners, github-actions-services

I need to send an email to github and then it need to run github action with input
Is that possible?

Or i need to make a push to master via email

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** start a workflow directly from email, but you can use [manual events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#manual-events)

> You can manually trigger a workflow run using the GitHub API and from GitHub. For more information, see "Manually running a workflow."

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows) are **all** available events that can trigger a workflow.

There are examples for starting workflow from slack, so I suppose you can implement something triggered by mail (if you can add a listener that checks all new emails and if specific email is send to call the GitHub API)